# LearnYouNode : connect ECONNREFUSED with http

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I'm currently learning NodeJS with the tutorial LearnYouNode. It's pretty great, but I'm stuck on an error, that I can't troubleshoot.

Here's a part of the code I try to run. It should work as expected (I check solutions, it's ok).

```
http.get(url+query, function(response){
    var content = "";
    response.setEncoding("utf8")
    response.on('data',function(data){
        content += String(data)
    })

    response.on('end',function(){
        content = JSON.parse(content)

        content.forEach(function(item){
            results.push(item.name)

        })
        return results
    })
}).on('error',function(e){
    console.log(e.message)
})
```

But it doesn't. That's why I made a log on 'error' event. Here's what it returns :

```
connect ECONNREFUSED
```

The thing is : **it just appeared suddently**, I didn't modify the code.

What's wrong there ?

Comment: If you put the url+query into your browser, what do you get?

Comment: It works, actually, I can put whatever (real) URL, it always return the same error.